# integrating roundcube or another MUA with dovecot/postfix already installed

Tags: ubuntu, email, postfix, dovecot, roundcube

I have gotten `dovecot` and postfix installed and working; I can send mail and receive it successfully on my linux Ubuntu 16.04 server.

As part of that installation I have a database named `servermail` with three tables:

```
virtual_aliases
virtual_domains
virtual_users
```

I can add email entries in this and the whole happy thing works great.

OK, soo.. now it's time install a MUA and I thought of Roundcube.  I've installed it but a) I can't log in as the install never set up the user account in the db that **IT** asked me to create, b) I had to find out the SQL table structure myself anyway [OK, I'm fine with that] but **c)** Why would I in my right mind have two separate databases?

So I guess the correct question is, how do I properly install a MUA like Roundcube when I already have a dovecot/postfix in place?

Answer (score 0):

RC have its own database for its own purposes like storing UI settings for each user. DB created by bundled `mysql_initial.sql`. POP/IMAP connections are configured manually in the `config.inc.php`:

```
// IMAP connection
$config['default_host']         = 'localhost';
$config['default_port']         = 143;
$config['imap_auth_type']       = PLAIN;
// SMTP connection
$config['smtp_server']          = 'localhost';
$config['smtp_port']            = 25;
$config['smtp_user']            = '%u';
$config['smtp_pass']            = '';
$config['smtp_auth_type']       = 'PLAIN';
```

For some reason I prefer to store passwords in the DB unencripted but you can use any encryption scheme you want until postfix/dovecot/roundcube all uses the same scheme.

I recommend to use `postfixadmin` as domain/account management tool as its database is well crafted for mais service (instead of `servermail` one).